# Powershell script for creating and naming a folder

Tags: powershell

Ok, I'll try again. This got deleted before I had a chance to reply.

I'm new to Powershell and I've tried with no success to build a script to create a new folder, prompt the user to name the folder, then copy/move files into the new folder from an external drive. I have searched your site and the Net, but no luck. Any advice please? Thanks.

I've used the following lines to create a folder and copy files to it:

```
new-item "C:\Users\Dan\Pictures\DANTEST" -type directory
Copy-Item H:1*.jpg "C:\Users\Dan\Pictures\DANTEST"
```

But that, as you can see, has a pre-determined folder name in the script. I've only found a VB Script that brings up a box for user input, but nothing on how to take the input and apply it to a new folder, then copy the files to that new folder.

Comment: Look up `Read-Host`.

Answer (score 2):

As vonPryz suggested, you can use `Read-Host` to prompt for the input of a folder name, then store it a variable which you can then include in your desired path.

Try:

```
 $folderName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input folder name' 
 new-item "C:\Users\Dan\Pictures\$folderName" -type directory 
 Copy-Item H:1*.jpg"C:\Users\Dan\Pictures\$folderName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, also read about creating Powershell Functions.

Create a script with the following at the top.  For example Copy-Files.ps1

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$directory)

Copy-Item H:1*.jpg "C:\Users\Dan\Pictures\$directory"
```

Now we run the script by doing:

```
PS C:\> .\Copy-Files MyFolder
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Gnarlywhale's answer did the trick. Going to try the second as well.  Thanks again.